# Where can I find a list of rxvt keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: linux, urxvt, rxvt

I started using `rxvt` terminal and noticed that commonly used shortcuts are not working. Like `ctrl+a` or `ctrl+e` to jump to line beginning and end, `ctrl + left` or `ctrl + right` to move over words. I have found the shortcuts for word navigation `alt + f` and `alt + b` but what about others?

Comment: This smells more like a termcap difference than rxvt per se. Try `export TERM=rxvt` and see what happens. Failing that, show us `echo $TERM` from a terminal where things work and where they don't work, and tell us which terminal emulator is running for each. (gnome-terminal, xterm, ...?)

Comment: Using **rxvt**: `echo $TERM` -> `rxvt-unicode-256color`, using **lxterminal**: `echo $TERM` -> `xterm`